# How to display a random photo from the gallery without picking it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, random, android-gallery

I want to create a flutter app that shows me a random photo from the phone gallery, I don't want to choose it like with the image picker, I would like a button that loads me a random image.

I've tried to create a list that contains every image from the phone but i can't make it work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.